# Cannot Create a Table With Foreign Key in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create this table in my php file:

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE Orders (orderID INT(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                  FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES Users (userID))");
```

However, whenever this query runs it doesn't create the table.

Am I creating the foreign key wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Echo result of `mysql_error()` after the query and you will see why the query is failing.

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE Orders (
    orderID INT(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES Users (userID)
 )") or die(mysql_error());
```

In your case, there is no column `userID`, and you are trying to create a foreign key on that column. You have to define the column first. Make sure it has exact the same data type as in `Users` table

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE Orders (
    orderID INT(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    userID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES Users (userID)
 )") or die(mysql_error());
```